# Low Graphics Mode Error

Tags: graphics

I have a Dell Inspiron 910 and am receiving a running in low graphics mode error.  I believe the error was caused by attempting to install a game I did not have the proper space for. I have tried a few of the fixes described in previous posts but have had no luck. I get messages that I have zero space remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting a few files from your home folder.

In case you have separate home, and the root partition is full,

- clean cached packages

  ```
  sudo apt-get clean
  ```
- remove old kernels and headers

  ```
  dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | xargs apt-get -y purge
  ```

To delete files from terminal, use the following commands:

```
cd /home/duane/ #change to the home folder

ls #list the files

rm file_name
```

Comment: How do I delete files in home folder from the terminal?  I only have access to root or terminal modes with the low graphics error.

Comment: See the update above.